# How to setup serial port connection using NW.js and chrome.serial API?

Tags: javascript, serial-port, google-chrome-app, nw.js

I think I can communicate with serial ports in NW.js without such dependencies as [node-serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) with precompiled binaries for different platforms.

Pure Node.js can't accomplish this task. But there's integrated Chrome API in NW.js and it has `chrome.serial` API, that can be used directly in JavaScript to setup serial port connection.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### List

First of all let's fetch list of devices available to communicate with:

```
chrome.serial.getDevices(function(ports) {
    for (let port of ports) {
        if (port.vendorId) {
            console.log(port);
        }
    }
});
```

You will get list of all ports with `vendorId` specified, i.e. existing devices.

Example result:

```
{
    displayName: 'Arduino Uno'
    path: 'COM7',
    productId: 67,
    vendorId: 9025
}
```

Property `path` then used for connection.

---

### Connect

To connect with default settings:

```
var path = 'COM7';

chrome.serial.connect(path, {}, function(CI) {
    console.log('Connection ID: '+ CI.connecionId);
    console.log(CI);
});
```

Now you're ready!